# Copying Reference assemblies locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a newbie question, say you are using **Visual Studio 2012 express** to compile an application, and you set **ALL** the reference assemblies to **COPY LOCAL = TRUE** it would include them in the application folder path right?, therefore installing **C++ Redistributable 2012** isn't necessary anymore, is that a true statement?, or do users still need to install that(C++ Redistributable 2012 ) to be able to run the Application?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is *not* true. If you are writing a .NET application, the user will need to have the appropriate version of the .NET Framework installed in order to run the application.

But your question is confused. None of that has anything to do with the C++ Redistributable Runtime Library. That will *also* have to be distributed, but it is completely separate from the .NET Framework. There are three possible ways of handling that dependency:

1. Installing the redistributable on the user's machine
2. Using app-local deployment and deploying the required CRT DLLs in the same directory as your EXE
3. Statically linking to the CRT

Each have their advantages and disadvantages. There isn't enough information in your question about your situation to make a recommendation.

Comment: Right and what about the C++ Redistributable 2012 is that still necessary if you copy all the reference assemblies?

Comment: Yes, that is still necessary. Those assemblies have nothing at all to do with the CRT library. You are confusing C++ with the .NET Framework.

Comment: is there confusing around running in dev environment versus the deployment approach?  What is the Setup.exe plan ? pre-req check for both libraries, install crt with custom app and get user to install only .net prior ... whatever, but understand that and you have a path forward